# Populate readonly input on text input condition

Tags: javascript

Relatively new to JS. Other answers I find don't seem to work for me here...

I'm trying to take a text input value [of type="number"], use a 'for' loop to match that value and populate a readonly input to display a price [based on number of units input]...

Many thnaks!

users input field:

```
<input class="form-control" name="input-users" id="input-users-bus" type="number" value="" onfocus="this.value = '' " onchange="calcUsers()" />
```

script (playing with at the minute):

```
var inputUsersBus = document.getElementById('input-users-bus').value;


function calcUsers(){
    for(x = 0; x<inputUsers; x++){
        if(x == inputUsers){
            document.getElementById('sum-price-bus').value = x;
            else{

            }
        }
    }

}
```

output field:

```
<input class="sum-price" name="sum" id="sum-price-bus" type="number" value="" onfocus="this.value = '' " readonly/>
```

Comment: So the number specified in `input-users-bus` determines the number of input fields that need to be entered by the user? For instance, if a user inputs `5` into the `input-users-bus` field, then they have to input 5 price values which'll be summed and outputted in `sum-price-bus`?

Comment: No exactly. All I'm trying to do here is get an input to 'input-users-bus', if that values is "5" for example, the output to 'sum-price-bus' needs to be "5".
[Later I'll work on the calculator to show the real price].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation that solves your problem. Whenever `input-users-bus` changes price, the value is grabbed using `getElementById('input-users-bus').value` and multiplied by the price variable. The readonly field `sum-price-bus`'s value is then set to the result.

```
<input class="form-control" name="input-users" id="input-users-bus" type="number" value="" onchange="calcUsers()" />
<input class="sum-price" name="sum" id="sum-price-bus" type="number" value="" readonly/>

<script>
var price = 5.00; // Acquire this price from whatever source you'd like    
function calcUsers() {
  var users = document.getElementById('input-users-bus').value;
  var result = users * price;
  document.getElementById('sum-price-bus').value = result;
}
</script>
```